# How to recursively crawl whole website using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, portia

I want to crawl complete website using scrapy but right now its only crawling single page

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import JsonItemExporter

class IzodspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):


name = 'izodspider'
allowed_domains = ['izod.com']
start_urls = ['http://izod.com/']
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
    meta = hxs.xpath('//meta[@name=\'description\']/@content').extract()
    name = hxs.xpath('//div[@id=\'product-details\']/h5').extract()
    desc = hxs.xpath('//div[@id=\'product-details\']/p').extract()
```

is there any way to extract meta tags using portia ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the rule definition and inside the callback.

Since the parse function you use is *parse_item* you have to call it inside the callback instead of *parse*

You can find more information about the callback function on the documentation here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=callback#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments

```
class IzodspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "izod"
depth_limit= 0 
bot_name = 'izod'
allowed_domains = ['izod.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.izod.com']
rules = (
     Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('')), callback='parse_items',follow= True),
     )

def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
    meta = hxs.xpath('//meta[@name=\'description\']/@content').extract()
    name = hxs.xpath('//div[@id=\'product-details\']/h5').extract()
    desc = hxs.xpath('//div[@id=\'product-details\']/p').extract()
```